# Angular ui Tour - not scrolling

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scroll, bootstrap-tour

I just implemented Angular Ui Tour (https://github.com/benmarch/angular-ui-tour) on my site, everything seems to work, except scrolling to the opened dialog.

I created and started the tour like that:

```
uiTourService.createDetachedTour('myTour');
this._uiTourService.getTourByName('myTour').start();
```

And the tour steps are defined like so:

```
<div tour-step tour-step-title="Main Menu" tour-step-content="Navigate the site using this menu."
     tour-step-order="0" tour-step-placement="bottom-left" tour-step-belongs-to="myTour"></div>
<p tour-step tour-step-title="second step" tour-step-content="this is the second step"
   tour-step-order="1" tour-step-placement="bottom" tour-step-belongs-to="myTour"></p>
```

Everything is shown correctly, i also managed to use my keyboard to navigate (arrow keys), setting `useHotkeys` to true. But the scrolling thing won't work, even if I try to set `scrollIntoView` to true manually.

Does anybody know, what the issue could be?

Answer (score 0):

I just run into this.

The scrolling part is the angular-smooth-scroll's job (angular-ui-tour uses it properly).

The minified version is the problematic, also it shows no error :/

So I switched to the source version (/dist/angular-smooth-scroll.min.js -> /lib/angular-smooth-scroll.js) and it's working just fine.